# Plot Integral trace in R

Tags: r

I would like to automate an analysis I have been doing with Graphpad Prism with R, but apparently it is harder than I thought.

I have Voltage~Time data that I would like to integrate and plot. In Graphpad Prism, this is performed by Analysis -> Integrate -> Create the Integral.

Here blow I plot the data in Prism and I plot the trace that I got from the Plot Integral command.

[image: Data]

[image: Integral of Data]

How can I do that with R?

The data I used are similar to these:

```
Time <- seq(1,100,1)
Voltage <- sample(1:1000,100, replace = F)
```

I tried `integrate()`, but that requires a function to integrate, which I do not have, and gives me just a number.
I tried `approxfun()` and I could create a function of my data but again, as soon as I apply 'integrate()' I only got a single value.

Do you have any ideas on what the Graphpad Prism function does and how I can translate that to R?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With discrete values you can use cumsum:

```
set.seed(1)

Time <- seq(1,100,1)
Voltage <- sample(1:1000,100, replace = F)

df = data.frame(Time, Voltage)

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(data = df)+
  geom_line(aes(x = Time, y = Voltage))

p2 <- ggplot(data = df)+
  geom_line(aes(x = Time, y = cumsum(Voltage)))


library(gridExtra)    
grid.arrange(p1, p2)][1]][1]
```

[image]

For unevenly spaced time values, you would want to calculate:

```
cumsum(df$Voltage[1:(nrow(df)-1)]) * diff(df$Time)
```

Comment: Thank you, the cumsum() function did work. Fantastic!